# Can not import library installed in Anaconda 2 while operating with different environments

Tags: python, import, path, anaconda, environment

I have Anaconda 2 with Python 2.7 running on Windows 8.  I have installed GraphLab and GraphLab has created a separate environment in Anaconda -- the gl-env environment.

I am facing problems in importing libraries that I have installed successfully via conda through the Windows Commander from the Scripts subdirectory.

For example, I installed wget successfully but when I try to import it from my Jupyter Notebook from the gl-env environment I get an error message that the module does not exist.

I suspect that this error has something to do with the two environments and the PATH content but I do not know enough to figure that out.  I made a research in Stackoverflow and it seems that other people have had importing problems relating to different environments but as far as I understand there is not specific advice I can implement.

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a cell in Jupyter directly identifying/appending the path...

```
import graphlab
graphlab.path.append(path)
```

...whatever the path may be.

Comment: Forgive me, but I do not understand.  What path I will pass as input to the append() method?  E.g. I have installed wget from the Scripts directory of Anaconda 2.  What exactly should I do to be able to import it from the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I imported graphlab as you indicated and I entered graphlab.path.append(path) having stored at path the path of the Scripts directory of Anaconda 2.  I got an error message: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path'

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you still need it, but for future users, once a new environment is created, once must install the specific libraries and modules one wants accessible in that environment.
In this case, once the gl-env is activated, do a `conda install wget` again.